# Creating multiple stored procs in C# code

Tags: c#, sql

I'm trying to execute a script in C# that will create multiple stored procedures in the SQL 2008 Database.

I tried putting them all in a single file but it errors out when I try that with

```
Incorrect syntax 'create procedure' must be the only statement in the batch.
```

If I put `GO` after the create procedure if fails with a syntax error on the word `GO`.

The C# code looks like this;

```
using (SqlConnection con = new SqlConnection(conString))
                {
                    con.Open();

                    foreach(string scriptFile in scriptFiles)
                    {
                        var command = con.CreateCommand();
                        command.CommandText = scriptFile;
                        int a = command.ExecuteNonQuery();
                        command.Dispose();
                        if (a == -1) successFlag = true;
                    }

                    con.Close();
                    con.Dispose();
                }
```

So I essentially have a bunch of Create Procedure calls in the same txt file that I want to execute on the database to create all the stored procs.

```
    Create PROCEDURE [dbo].[msp_AddBulkNewEmployeeUploadDetails]      
    snip
    CREATE PROCEDURE [dbo].[msp_AddNewEmployeeDetails]
    snip
```

Is there a way to do this in a single file rather than in multiple files?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You will need to separate each procedure definition with a `GO`, parse on the `GO` (and remove it) and run each procedure in individually.

An alternative is to use a ready rolled tool like [DBUp](https://github.com/DbUp/DbUp).

Whatever you are already using to create your `scriptFiles` collection, just needs to do that GO parsing.

There is a benefit to having 1 file per stored procedure: it makes version control (and version comparisons) easier.

Comment: Right, so you are saying I need to essentially split the file on "GO" and parse each section individually right?